# Two different html tables highlight the same rows order

Tags: javascript, css, html-table

I have a question, I am trying to make some manipulation with html tables. I have two tables,
and when I hover first row from the first table, it should highlight both rows from both tables.

I have found a solution, in making this simple function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function matchrow(){
document.getElementById('row1').style.backgroundColor='#f5f5f5'; 
}
function unmatchrow(){
document.getElementById('row1').style.backgroundColor='white';
}        
</script>
```

On the first table I have:

```
<tr onmouseover="matchrow()" onmouseout="dismatchrow()" >
```

on the second table I have:

```
<tr id="row1" >
```

So when I put mouseover the first row from the first table, the first row from the second table highlights.

My question is, how to make it for the every single row, especially if it will be dynamic table.
Hope I was clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've implemented this with jQuery. It doesn't use obtrusive JS and doesn't require additional IDs for rows.
Also, CSS classes are more preferable than inline styles.

HTML:

```
<table id="t1">
    <tr><td>......</td></tr>
    <tr><td>......</td></tr>
</table>
<br/>
<table id="t2">
    <tr><td>......</td></tr>
    <tr><td>......</td></tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
tr.active > td
{
    background-color:#f00;
}
```

JS:

```
$(function(){
    $("#t1 tr").hover(
        function(){
            $(this).addClass('active');
            $('#t2 tr:eq(' + $('#t1 tr').index($(this)) + ')').addClass('active');
        },
        function(){
            $(this).removeClass('active');
            $('#t2 tr:eq(' + $('#t1 tr').index($(this)) + ')').removeClass('active');
        }
    );
});
```

Here is live fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/keaukraine/KBEhA/1/

Answer (score 1):

You can use the div id as a parameter in the function

```
 <tr onmouseover="matchrow('row1')" onmouseout="dismatchrow('row1')">

 function matchrow(divid){
      document.getElementById(divid).style.backgroundcolor='#F5F5F5';
 }
 function dismatchrow(divid){
      document.getElementById(divid).style.backgroundcolor='white';
 }
```

Comment: Thanks that worked well. But do you have some clues, how to make it, if tables rows would be added dynamically? Anyway thanks for this tip!

Comment: You can use a loop function to change the div id for each row

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery for this.

Use the [.eq()](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) and [.index()](http://api.jquery.com/index/) functions.

A way of doing it:

HTML:

```
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td>Row1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Row2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Row3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Row4</td>
    </tr>
</table>

<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td>Row1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Row2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Row3</td>
    </tr>    
</table>
```

JS:

```
$('table tr').hover(function()
{
    var index = $(this).index();
    $('table').each(function()
    {
        $(this).find('tr').eq(index).css('color', 'red');
    });
});
```

A working example can be found [here](http://jsfiddle.net/HhU8B/1/).